# AMPscript List subscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I'm using the following SSJS to unsubscribe a contact from a list. Just wondering, how can I use the same logic to subscribe a contact to list? Can't find anything.

```
<script runat=server>

    Platform.Load("Core","1");

    var lid = xx;
    var subkey = Variable.GetValue("@contact");
    var email = Variable.GetValue("@email");

    // Use LogUnsubEvent to maintain reporting, rather than update pub list directly
    lue = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ExecuteRequest");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent");

    lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", subkey);
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

    lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "ListID");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", lid);
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

    lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "Reason");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", "Profile Center Unsubscribe");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

    var statusAndRequest = [0,0];

    try{
        Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);
        // Write(Stringify(Response));
    } catch(err){
        // Write(Stringify(err));
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to use the API functions, there's a helper function for it:

```
<script runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

var sub = {
    "SubscriberKey": "SUBSCRIBERKEY",
    "Lists": [{"Status": "Active", "ID": 12345, "Action": "Upsert"}]
};

try {

  var subObj = Subscriber.Init("SUBSCRIBERKEY");
  var status = subObj.Upsert(sub);

} catch (e) {
  // error handling here
}

</script>
```

Reference:

[**Subscriber Functions: Upsert**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/subscriber_server_side_javascript_functions/upsert/)

Comment: There's a "{" bracket missing in front of the catch, but besides that, it's working perfect. thanks!

Comment: Hi just wondering, why use upsert rather than update here?

Comment: `Subscriber.Init("SUBSCRIBERKEY)";` should read `Subscriber.Init("SUBSCRIBERKEY");` :-)

Comment: Updated.  Thanks for pointing out the issue.